# Could not import runpy module in python virtual environment

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

while trying to run memory profiler (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) in virtual environment using bash /activate, I couldnt run any of the default test code

```
python -m memory_profiler test/test_as.py
Could not import runpy module
```

while it runs fine in another virtual env,

```
 > python -m memory_profiler ./test/test_as.py
 Filename: ./test/test_as.py
 Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
 ================================================
 3    9.199 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
 4                             def f():
 5    9.207 MiB    0.008 MiB       o = math.sqrt(2013)
 6    9.207 MiB    0.000 MiB       return o
```

How do I import the runpy module or install it using pip or easy install ?
or do a manual installation of module?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting the environment and creating a new one with virtualenv worked for me ... I couldn't find any other solution when I hit this, this morning

Comment: Yes, @Neil, I eventually had to do the same.  But was wondering, after following the same sequence of steps to setup the virtual Env, one env could find it and the other couldnt...

Comment: Deleting too does not work for me.I used  pipenv uninstall --all
 command